# Geoserver SLD style - Labeling lines with shields

Tags: geoserver, sld

I'm novice in Geoserver (Geoserver 2.10.0 in Tomcat 9 + Apache 2.14, on Win 10 Pro x64)
 and for some time trying to style roads labels as shields for highways, principal hwy ...

Checked Geoserver Trainings/sld-references/cookbook but can't locate any "real life" example with complete code.

Made and export SLD for line styles with QGIS 2.18.1, but since labels aren't supported, used OSGB SLD as a source code :

https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/Strategi-stylesheets/blob/master/ESRI%20Shapefile%20stylesheets/GeoServer%20stylesheets%20(SLD)/Full%20Colour%20style/motorway.sld#L348

and copy/paste   **TextSymbolizer... /TextSymbolizer** portion of the code regarding label shields into Geoserver sld file -

( *also edit original code with se:, ogc:, se:SvgParameter* )

```
  <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>MARKED_TR labels</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>MARKED_TR</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>GRMN_TYPE</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>MARKED_TR</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:MaxScaleDenominator>250000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
     <se:TextSymbolizer>
       <se:Label>
         <ogc:PropertyName>NAME_UTF</ogc:PropertyName>
       </se:Label>
       <se:Font>
         <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Arial</se:SvgParameter>
         <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">9</se:SvgParameter>
         <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">bold</se:SvgParameter>
       </se:Font>
        <se:LabelPlacement>
          <se:PointPlacement>
            <se:AnchorPoint>
              <se:AnchorPointX>0.5</se:AnchorPointX>
              <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
            </se:AnchorPoint>
            <se:Displacement>
              <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
              <se:DisplacementY>0</se:DisplacementY>
            </se:Displacement>
          </se:PointPlacement>
        </se:LabelPlacement>
       <se:Fill>
         <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</se:SvgParameter>
       </se:Fill>
       **<se:Graphic>**
         <se:Mark>
           <se:WellKnownName>square</se:WellKnownName>
           <se:Fill>
             <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#009FB8</se:SvgParameter>
           </se:Fill>
         </se:Mark>
         <se:Size>6</se:Size>
       </se:Graphic>
       <se:Priority>450</se:Priority>
       <se:VendorOption name="graphic-resize">stretch</se:VendorOption>
       <se:VendorOption name="graphic-margin">2.3</se:VendorOption>
       <se:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">200</se:VendorOption>
       <se:VendorOption name="repeat">500</se:VendorOption>       
       <se:VendorOption name="spaceAround">10</se:VendorOption>
       <se:VendorOption name="group">yes</se:VendorOption>  
     </se:TextSymbolizer>          
   </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Unfortunately, Geoserver Validation returns error as shown in screenshot:

[image: Geoserver screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not validate because it is an extension to the SLD standard schema. If you press `submit` and view the map you will see it works just fine.

Comment: everything are displayed properly ... font/position/orientation ... except the shield itself

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot with "invisible" shield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyUIt.png)

As of now, it's seems that syntax in section
**Graphic -- /Graphic** isn't correct ?!